# How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac 1t}t^{-p}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What substitution can I use to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac 1t}t^{-p}$$
where $p = \frac 32 + \frac n2$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$? I have no clue. For $p=2$ it is easy but for the other values of $p$ I don't know.

Comment: Of course (??), it is $\;dt\;$ ...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitution:

$$t=\frac1u\implies dt=-\frac{du}{u^2}\implies$$

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-1/t}t^{-p}dt=\int_\infty^0e^{-u} u^p\left(-\frac{du}{u^2}\right)=$$

$$=\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{p-2}du=\Gamma(p-1)\;,\;\;\text{assuming $\;\;$Re}(p-1)>0$$